# Finding Lists from Smaller Items from Other Lists

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I'm currently creating a project that involves keeping track of lists of machines to build and the items to build it within those lists. However, I'd like to extend the functionality further and show the user other machines that could be built (or the percentage of it) with the items saved to the system.

This project is part of an Android app, and the machine lists and the parts within them are pulled off an external REST API, just for background.

I've tried searching for some resources, however I think it's quite hard to put what I'm trying to do into a short query. Forgive me if this has already been asked, but I'm not quite sure how to start on this and any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very classic problem. [`Java enums`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are a fantastic tool to solve this exact problem.

Here is an example of something similar I am working on.

```java
import java.util.*;

private class SOQ_20221219_2 {
    private enum Tool { HAMMER, NAIL, DRILL, SCREW, SAW, WOOD, METAL, ; }

    private enum Project {
        WORK_BENCH(Tool.HAMMER, Tool.NAIL, Tool.SAW, Tool.WOOD),
        STOP_SIGN(Tool.DRILL, Tool.SCREW, Tool.METAL),
        SHED(Tool.HAMMER, Tool.NAIL, Tool.DRILL, Tool.SCREW, Tool.SAW, Tool.WOOD, Tool.METAL),
        TOOL_HANGER(Tool.HAMMER, Tool.NAIL, Tool.WOOD),
        ;

        public final Set<Tool> requiredTools;

        Project(Tool... requiredTools) {
            this.requiredTools = Set.of(requiredTools);
        }

        public boolean canMakeWithGivenTools(Set<Tool> givenTools) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(givenTools);
            return givenTools.containsAll(this.requiredTools);
        }
    }

    public SOQ_20221219_2() {
        final Set<Tool> tools = EnumSet.of(Tool.HAMMER, Tool.NAIL, Tool.SAW, Tool.WOOD);
        for (final Project eachProject : Project.values()) {
            if (eachProject.canMakeWithGivenTools(tools)) {
                System.out.println(eachProject + " can be made with " + tools);
            }
        }
    }
}
```